# AWS Athena: Handling big numbers

Tags: biginteger, presto, amazon-athena

I have files on S3 where two columns contain only positive integers which can be of `10^26`. Unfortunately, according to [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html) Athena only supports values in a range up to `2^63-1` (approx `10^19`). So at the moment these column are represented as a string.

When it comes to filtering it is not that big of an issue, as I can use regex. For example, if I want to get all records between `5e^21` and `6e^21` my query would look like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM database.table
WHERE (regexp_like(col_1, '^5[\d]{21}$'))
```

I have approx **300M** rows (approx 12GB in parquet) and it takes about 7 seconds, so performance wise it ok.

However, sometimes I would like to perform some math operation on these two big columns, e.g subtract one big column from another. Casting these records to DOUBLE wouldn't work due to approximation error. Ideally, I would want to stay within Athena. At the moment, I have about **100M** rows that are greater then `2^63-1`, but this number can grow in a future.

What would be the right way to approach problem of having numerical records that exceed available range? Also what are your thoughts on using regex for filtering? Is there a better/more appropriate way to do it?

Comment: How/why did the columns ever get stored in scientific notation anyways? Integers, even bigintegers, are normally stored with all their digits in some convenient base like 10 or 16.

Comment: This is how historical data arrived from the provider) Initially, I didn't even notice it. It came up when I attempted to repartition data and convert it to parquet with [CTAS queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html)

Comment: I guess my suspicion is that the data is already only approximate, and possibly very low precision. You would likely lose nothing by converting to double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast numbers of the form `5e21` to an approximate 64bit [`double`](https://trino.io/docs/current/language/types.html#double) or an exact numeric 128bit [`decimal`](https://trino.io/docs/current/language/types.html#decimal).  First you'll need to remove the caret `^`, with the [replace](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#replace) function.  Then a simple `cast` will work:

```sql
SELECT CAST(replace('5e^21', '^', '') as DOUBLE);
 _col0  
--------
 5.0E21
```

or

```sql
SELECT CAST(replace('5e^21', '^', '') as DECIMAL);
         _col0          
------------------------
 5000000000000000000000
```

If you are going to this table often, I would rewrite it the new data type to save processing time.

Comment: thanks, don't know why I haven't tried to cast it as decimal) But what would be a good solution when you have to be precise let's say up to 50 decimal places?